# C++: Arbitrary function as argument of function

Tags: c++, function, variadic-functions

Suppose I want to write a general numerical integration script, which takes a user-defined function and integrate over the variable `int x`. Further suppose the function can call an arbitrary number of lists of data; e.g. suppose I want the integrator `f_integrator` to be able to integrate any of the following:

`integrand(x)=f(x)`

`integrand(x)=f(x)*g(x)`

`integrand(x)=(f(x)+g(x)/h(x))`

`integrand(x)=pow(f(x),2)*k(x)`

Then it seems we need it to be able to call for *just a well-defined function*, without specifying how many arguments the function takes (maybe we need to specify part of them, such as the functions must have an `int x`). If this is so, then how can we implement it? If we should do it in another way, how?

Comment: pas the function a list of arguments using a vector or some such, perhaps a dictionary (map).

Comment: I don't understand the part about "how many arguments the function takes". All your examples seem to be functions taking one argument.  Also, you can't numerically integrate a function whose domain can only have integer values.

Comment: `f_integrator([f,g,h] (int x) { return (f(x)+g(x))/h(x); });`?

Comment: I don't see how you jump to the conclusion `without specifying how many arguments the function takes`. I think you need to articulate what you are trying to achieve rather than telling us how you think you should solve it.

Comment: If you don't know how many arguments your function is taking, you cannot do anything with it. So perhaps you need to think some more about what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe I should have written the integrand definitions in full. Since this is numerical integration, `f` `g` `h` would come from data lists (say they are stored as vectors), so the function `integrand` must take all these vectors as arguments as well. I omitted the technical details of how exactly the numerical integration would be to be done.

Comment: Maybe it is better then to make integrand some class that has these vectors as members. I suppose these data lists do not change during the integration, so the integrand's operator() does not really need them as explicit arguments.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variadic template for `f_integrator` if you need to pass an unknown number of arguments

```
template<typename F, typename... Args >
double f_integrator(F integrand, std::tuple<Args...> const &bounds){
// integrate
}
```

to allow it to work on functions taking arbitrary argument types (assuming the integral is of type `double`, one can also add another template parameter for the return type, if required). The template parameter `F` takes the role of the function type. You can then call `f_integrator` directly on the function, e.g. a lambda like

```
 double integral = f_integrate([](double x){return f(x)*g(x);},
                               std::make_tuple(1.0,2.0));
```

Note that you can pass any callable object to `f_integrate`, given that callable returns something you can integrate.

Using `std::tuple` allows for passing the bounds of the integration area in a way they are somewhat processable in the function body. Of course, if you consider non-trivial integration areas, things get more complicated, but you can still pass a grid represented by an array of `Args` to pass the information on the integration area to `f_integrator`.

How the integration itself is performed is a different story, but iteratively integrating over one argument after another is not very efficient, in case you want to do high-dimensional integrals, Monte-Carlo integration might be a good approach.

This is a very general solution, and given some mild assumptions, there are much more convenient ways of implementing that (writing the body of the integrator is not quite trivial for the variadic template). If all arguments of the integrand are of the same type, we can pass the bounds just as a normal vector like

```
template<typename F, typename T>
double f_integrate(F integrand, std::vector<T> const &bounds){
  // integrate, much more convenient
}
```

Now, the examples you provided only require a single argument, so in case you are fine with integrating one-dimensional functions, you can do it a bit simpler. If you are passing just functions with a single argument, you don't need the variadic template, you are fine with just

```
template<typename F, typename T=double>
double f_integrate(F integrand, T const& lower_bound, T const& upper_bound){
   // integrate
}
```

Probably, the second parameter is not even necessary, as you might exclusively integrate over the real numbers (note that an integration over integers is just a discrete sum, so there is no need for performing the integration numerically in that case).